# How to change the frame of AlertView in iPhone App...?

Tags: iphone

I want to Add TextBox on AlertView. But When i'm adding, it overlaps little with buttons on it...So i want to increase the height and width of alertview...Could Anybody tell any idea??

Comment: try to accept your previous answers then more people will help you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
UIAlertView alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Title", nil) 
                                                  message:NSLocalizedString(@"Message\n\n\n", nil)
                                                 delegate:self 
                                        cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", nil)
                                        otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", nil), nil];

    UITextField textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(16.0, 100.0, 250.0, 25.0)];
    textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;

    [alertView addSubview:textField];
    [textField release];
    [alertView show];
    [alertView release];
```

Comment: Thanks!! Its working..Actually I'm doing in the same way but not using "\n\n\n".Thats why textbox is overlapping with buttons.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
UITextField *TextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(22.0, 50.0, 240.0, 30.0)];

 UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Enter\n\n" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil]; 
[alertView addSubview:TextField];
[alertView show];
```

Comment: Thanks!! Its working..Actually I'm doing in the same way but not using "\n\n\n".Thats why textbox is overlapping with buttons.